# C#/Mac: Path.GetInvalidPathChars() and Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars() result

Tags: c#, macos, mono, path, platform-specific

What does this display on OSX? Can anyone run this on their machines using Mono?

```
foreach (char c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
{
   Console.Write((byte)c);
   Console.Write(", ");
}
```

and what does this display:

```
foreach (char c in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
{
   Console.Write((byte)c);
   Console.Write(", ");
}
```

For reference, I'm including the output of **GetInvalidPathChars** in Windows and Linux.

Output in Windows:
34, 60, 62, 124, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 1
8, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,

Output in openSUSE:
0,

Furthermore, I'm including the output of **GetInvalidFileNameChars** in Windows and Linux.

Output in Windows:
34, 60, 62, 124, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 1
8, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 58, 42, 63, 92, 47,

Output in openSUSE:
0, 47,

Regards,

_NT

Comment: Nice reference. For the benefit of other readers, `GetInvalid*Chars` are not guaranteed to retrieve _all_ invalid chars on a platform, but all returned chars are supposed to be invalid.

Comment: In your example code you are casting the characters to byte. This destroys the information you want; you'll get back numbers that are potentially meaningless. You should cast to int instead.

Answer (score 2):

The output on Mac OS X is the same as on Linux:

GetInvalidPathChars: 0,
GetInvalidFileNameChars: 0, 47,

Comment: It would be interesting to run this on differently mounted filesystems. Can someone run this on Linux or Mac when run from a FAT filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant code from Mono on Github:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs#L540

When not running on Windows, both methods only return the null character and the `GetInvalidFileNameChars` additionally the forward slash character. There doesn't seem to be any difference regarding what non-Windows operating system or file system is used.